# ¿Cómo deserializar una cadena JSON a un objeto en C#?

Tags: c#, json

Recibo una variable llamada `productos` que contiene un listado de productos en formato `JSON` de la siguiente forma:

```
[{"codigo":"Servilleta","cantidad":2},{"codigo":"Papelhig","cantidad":1}]
```

Requiero deserializarla para poder usa los productos por separado dentro del método.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
public XmlDocument prueba(string cliente, string productos)
{
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    var stringdata = "<items>";
    stringdata += "<item>";
    stringdata += "<cliente> " + cliente + "</cliente>";
    stringdata += "<producto> " + productos + "</producto>";
    stringdata += "</item>";
    stringdata += "</items>";
    xml.LoadXml(stringdata);

    return xml;
}
```

Comment: muestra el código donde recibes la variable, es decir la llamada al webservice.

Comment: Ese es el metodo del web service que recibe en la variable productos lo siguiente: [{"codigo":"Servilleta","cantidad":2},{"codigo":"Papelhig","cantidad":1}]

Comment: var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(productos);
            Console.WriteLine("codigo: " + data.codigo + " cantidad: " + data.cantidad );

Comment: Gracias daniel por contestar ... lo intento y me sale lo siguiente "JsonConvert = doest not exist in the current context" y "dynamic" = the type or name space could not be found

Comment: Te falta agregar el nuget de NewtonSoft

Comment: @DanielVorph la cadena tiene formato de un listado y no de un objeto, por ende, cuando ejecute el código que incluyes en el comentario arrojaría un error.

Comment: @Davilo no marca error ya lo he probado así, es un objeto dinámico

Comment: @DanielVorph, podrías revisar: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IfElm4 e indicarme porque sale el error: `Run-time exception (line 12): 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' does not contain a definition for 'codigo'`. Solo he copiado y pegado el código de tu comentario.

Comment: ¿Alguna respuesta te fue de utilidad?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Sin usar clase intermedia:**

Referencias:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Dynamic;
```

En tu método:

```
var listProductos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ExpandoObject>>(productos);

foreach(dynamic prod in listProductos){
    Console.WriteLine("Código: " + prod.codigo + " - Cantidad: " + prod.cantidad );
}
```

Obtendrás

> ```
> Código: Servilleta - Cantidad: 2
> Código: Papelhig - Cantidad: 1
> ```

[**DEMO**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jEHSL4)

---

**Utilizando una clase:**

Creas la clase `Producto`:

```
public class Producto{
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public int Cantidad { get; set; }
}
```

En tu método:

```
var productos = "[{\"codigo\":\"Servilleta\",\"cantidad\":2},{\"codigo\":\"Papelhig\",\"cantidad\":1}]";

var listProductos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Producto>>(productos);

foreach(Producto prod in listProductos){
    Console.WriteLine("Código: " + prod.Codigo + " - Cantidad: " + prod.Cantidad);
}
```

Obtendrás:

> ```
> Código: Servilleta - Cantidad: 2
> Código: Papelhig - Cantidad: 1
> ```

[**DEMO**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sHarbG)

---

**Utilizando una lista anónima:**

Creas un objeto y una lista anónima que servirán como definición para deserializar.

```
var definicion = new { Codigo = "", Cantidad = 0 };
var listaDefinicion = new[] { definicion };

var productos = "[{\"codigo\":\"Servilleta\",\"cantidad\":2},{\"codigo\":\"Papelhig\",\"cantidad\":1}]";

var listProductos = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(productos, listaDefinicion);

foreach(var prod in listProductos){
    Console.WriteLine("Código: " + prod.Codigo + " - Cantidad: " + prod.Cantidad);
}
```

> ```
> Código: Servilleta - Cantidad: 2
> Código: Papelhig - Cantidad: 1
> ```

[**DEMO**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EKkcA9)

---

**Referencia:**

- [Deserialize an Object](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm)
- [Deserialize an Anonymous Type](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar NewtonSoft Json (Es un complemento o dll que necesitas agregar al proyecto para poder utilizarla)

Aquí te pongo el ejemplo([liga](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm)):

Necesitas el objeto al que se va a castear tu json

```
public class Account
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Después usas la función: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

```
string json = @"{
   'Email': 'james@example.com',
   'Active': true,
   'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',
   'Roles': [
     'User',
     'Admin'
  ]
 }";

Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);

Console.WriteLine(account.Email);
```

Para agregar NewtonSoft a tu proyecto utiliza los nugets:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Respondiendo la pregunta:

> En el caso del OP es un array que necesita deserializar ¿Como puede
>   hacerlo?

El JSON (se recibe como string) que utiliza el OP tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
[{"codigo":"Servilleta","cantidad":2},{"codigo":"Papelhig","cantidad":1}]
```

1. Debe crear el objeto para castearlo.  Tendria que ser algo asi:

   ```
    public class Producto
    {
        public string codigo{ get; set; }
        public decimal cantidad{ get; set; }
    }
   ```
2. Al momento de deserialiarlo tendria que hacer algo asi:

   ```
    List<Producto> productos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Producto>>(json);
   ```

[Anexo un ejemplo](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1NrUmB-KIz6VnFlNlZNV293Zms)

Comment: En el caso del OP es un array que necesita deserializar ¿Como puede hacerlo?